# Split a react routing component in two

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I built a react component to definite different routes
Here is the source of my Switch component

```js
function Switch() {
  return (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        /*
        ---- Routes on the Surveys List ---------------------------
        */
        <Route path="/examples/surveyslist" component={SurveysList}>

          <Route path="/examples/summary" component={Summary} />
          <Route path="/examples/survey" component={SurveyResult}>
            <Route path="/examples/survey/resultview" component={ResultView} />
            <Route
              path="/examples/survey/surveyproto"
              component={SurveyProto}
            />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/examples/survey/edit" component={SurveyForm} />
        </Route>
        /* ------------------- SurveysList ------------------------- */
        <Route path="/examples/employees" component={Employees} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This works well !
What I would like to do is to extract all the part between the comment lines to increase readability
I tried to make a function in the same js file add call it inside the switch component but it failed
I tried to make a SurveysSwitch component and export / import it but it failed too.
Any method ?
PS : I am a very newbie to webdev

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is:

```
function surveys() {
    return (
        <Route path="/examples/surveyslist" component={ SurveysList }>
            <Route path="/examples/summary" component={ Summary } />
            <Route path="/examples/survey" component={ SurveyResult }>
                <Route path="/examples/survey/resultview" component={ ResultView } />
                <Route
                    path="/examples/survey/surveyproto"
                    component={ SurveyProto }
                />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/examples/survey/edit" component={ SurveyForm } />
        </Route>
    );
}

function routes() {
    return (
        <Router history={ hashHistory }>
            <Route path="/" component={ App }>
                { this.surveys() }
                <Route path="/examples/employees" component={ Employees } />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

or, if you prefer a component

```
class Surveys extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Route path="/examples/surveyslist" component={ SurveysList }>
                <Route path="/examples/summary" component={ Summary } />
                <Route path="/examples/survey" component={ SurveyResult }>
                    <Route path="/examples/survey/resultview" component={ ResultView } />
                    <Route
                        path="/examples/survey/surveyproto"
                        component={ SurveyProto }
                    />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/examples/survey/edit" component={ SurveyForm } />
            </Route>
        );
    }
}
```

then you would replace `{ this.surveys() }` with `<Surveys />`.

Comment: Thank you Tyler
The solution with 2 functions works (changing this.surveys by surveys)
WIth the component solution I get a message "Location "/examples/surveyslist" did not match any routes"